# Get Discord bot to reply to itself

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a discord bot that will spit out a random response. Some responses include a die roll.

What I would like is if a random response is give that includes a die roll, for the bot to automatically roll the die.

At the moment I am just trying to get it to respond to itself.

I'm new to python/discord.py so please forgive my ignorance

Basic code:

```
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


# user types a trigger command
if message.content.startswith('.trigger'):
        choice= [
            "One of many options, lets roll 1d4"
        ]
        result = random.choice(choice)    # I'm doing other bits with the result so hence assigning it to a variable here
        await message.channel.send(result)

# If there is the term 1d4 in the choice message, roll the dice
if '1d4' in message.content:
        roll = random.randrange(1, 4)
        await message.channel.send(f'{"**Result** = "+ str(roll)}')
```

I don't thing I'm checking to see if the bot is posting the message or anything

Comment: This is `discord.py` not `discord.js` which stands for Discord *JavaScript*

Comment: opps. Sorry, you are correct. I've been looking though alot of discord things and got wires crossed

Answer (score 1):

One of those cases where to figure out the answer, just ask.

Removed the line

```
if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

And it is working how I wanted

Thanks for being my rubber ducky!